# Callback is not setting variable?

Tags: node.js

So I have a callback that obtains the port to listen on from a SQL server like so below and a looped output.

```
var ServerPort;
sql.ObtainPort(function(res){
    SeverPort = res;
    server.listen(res);
    console.log("Server Started");
});
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Loop "+ServerPort);
},1000/30);
```

Console:

```
Loop undefined
Loop undefined
Loop undefined
8088
8088
Server Started
Loop undefined
Loop undefined
Loop undefined
Loop undefined
Loop undefined
```

Now when SeverPort = res; was set it should have became "Loop 8080" but it didn't it remained undefined. I am missing something here. Can someone help out?

Comment: In order to help, you'll need to reveal a little more code. Specifically the code that prints "Loop ...".

Comment: woops look now.

Comment: You'll also want to update the output you provided, as no part of your code will emit the bare string "8080".  If the output is up to date, lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

```
SeverPort = res;
```

should be

```
ServerPort = res;
```

now I feel dumb.